# Control the playback of HTML5 video control inside webview through native methods

Tags: android, webview, html5-video

I am trying to control the playback controls of a HTML5 video component inside my webview from within my native code in Android.
Is there any possible way to achieve that?
I wish to pause, resume and seek control the video in webview from the native Android code.
Are there any APIs available which can channel through and execute the javascript on the webview?

Any help or guidance is appreciated much.

Comment: You can do that by implementing a custom JavaScript interface.

Comment: Sounds good. How can I go about doing that? Any guides or references?

Comment: You can follow the guides on the official docs here https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview ,  Or search Google for tutorials on how to add custom JavaScript interface to your Android app..